# Filter nested Django objects in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In an application I am working on I would like to filter the objects returned by a serializer based on the user's is_staff status.  If a user has is_staff = True I would like for all of the nested Book objects to be returned. If the user's is_staff status is False I would like for only Books with active = True.  How can I achieve this using this viewset:

```
class BookCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    View available books by category
    """
    queryset = BookCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookCategorySerializer
```

and these serializers:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialize Book for list endpoint
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'category',
            'category_name',
            'thumbnail',
            'active',
        )

class BookCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialize books by category
    """
    books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='book_set')

    class Meta:
        model = BookCategory
        fields = (
            'name',
            'active',
            'books',
        )
```

NOTE: I am trying to filter the Books not the BookCategories based on the user status.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this to set the queryset in your view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_staff:
        return BookCategory.objects.all()
    else:
        return BookCategory.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Comment: This would filter the BookCategory objects not the Books that are active within the Category wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah but the problem was how to achive user right?so you can filter books too.the view you sent was for bookcategory so I filtered that.I think the problem is solved by this example.

Comment: I am actually trying to filter the Books so I only get the active books based on the user's status.

Comment: @JakeMulhern the view you sent was about bookcategory.just use this function with book model instead of bookcategory and the problem is solved bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to your serializer by overriding the list method and filter data based on that information:

views.py

```py
class BookCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    View available books by category
    """

    queryset = BookCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookCategorySerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        is_staff = self.request.user.is_staff
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            queryset, many=True, context={"is_staff": is_staff}
        )
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

By default [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is read-only

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialize Book for list endpoint
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'category',
            'thumbnail',
            'active',
        )

class BookCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialize books by category
    """
    books = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BookCategory
        fields = (
            'name',
            'active',
            'books',
        )
    
    def get_books(self, obj):
        is_staff = self.context.get('is_staff', None)
        books = obj.books.all()
        if not is_staff:
            books = books.filter(active=True)
        return BookSerializer(books, many=True).data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class BookCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = BookCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookCategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_admin:
            return qs.prefetch_related('book_set')
        else:
            return (
                qs.prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('book_set', Book.objects.filter(active=True))
                )
                .filter(active=True, book_set__active=True)
                .distinct()
            )
```

this will only load the `Book`s with `active=True` as `book_set`.